# Passing keycode with keydown and keyup events in Watir & FireWatir

Tags: jquery, ruby, watir, firewatir

I need to automate interaction with a custom jQuery rich text editor in our web client.
Having talked with our developers I would only need to be able to fire the following events;
keydown, keyup, mousedown, mouseup and paste.

So really need a way of being able to pass a key code with the fire_event keydown and keyup calls for WATIR and FIREWATIR?

Has anyone had any success in doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the send_keys method?  I know watir-webdriver supports it, and it seems that is rapidly becoming the preferred way of driving firefox

Comment: Finally got a web-driver test machine setup and this works using, a command like browser.frame(:id,"ws-txt-editor").div(:id,"proxy").send_keys "Hello World"

Comment: Woot  always glad to hear when my answers work.  Thanks for updating the question.  I think I'm going to be tempted to try a lot more stuff with watir-webdriver myself. it's seeming like the way of the future especially for cross browser support.

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar need a long time ago. I believe, your best bet is

```
@browser.document.parentWindow.eval(‘javascript’)
```

I've just tried the following on some page with included jquery:

```
$('body').keydown(function(e) {alert(e.keyCode)}); // Assign keydown event to 'body', so it will alert with the key code of any button pressed

var event = jQuery.Event("keydown");
event.keyCode = 50; // Whatever keyCode you need
jQuery("body").trigger(event); // Here you replace 'body' with the element you need
```

so, basically, you craft an event and trigger it on any element you need

the whole picture might look something like:

```
@browser.document.parentWindow.eval('var event = jQuery.Event("keydown"); event.keyCode = 50; jQuery("#theElementYouNeed").trigger(event)')
```

Comment: let us know the results, i feel there's some other solutions ;)